# Celery task_success signal parameters

Tags: python, django, celery

Using Celery 4.1.0
I'm trying to use Celery signals.
When using `@task_success` I'm trying to read the parameters I'm supposed to get and they're all None.

This is the signal:

```
@task_success.connect()
def task_succeeded(result, sender=None, task_id=None, task=None, **kwargs):
    print("result: " + str(result))
    print("task_id: " + str(task_id))
    print("task: " + str(task))
    print("sender: " + str(sender))
    print("request_id:" + sender.request.id)
```

The signal does get triggered and I see some printing, but seems like all the parameters' values are None. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

Reading the documentation for [signals](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.1.0/userguide/signals.html#task-success), `task_success` only accepts two params: `sender` and `result`.

`sender` is the  current [`Task`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.1.0/reference/celery.app.task.html#module-celery.app.task) while `result` is the current result of the task execution.

So, in your example, you are trying to read some params that are not defined and `result` and `sender` are also swapped.

P.D.: I'm answering quite late to this question, but I came across this while searching for `task_success` in google. Maybe will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
@signals.task_success.connect
def task_success_handler(sender=None, result=None,**kwargs):
    # Extract information from the result, such as task ID or any relevant data
    task_id = sender.request.id
    result = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery)
    state = result.state
    status = result.status
    print('\n\n Sucess task Id', task_id)
    print('\n\n Sucess task state', state)
    print('\n\n Sucess task status', status)
    print('\n\n\n sucesscalled')
```

Above code worked for me

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation about **why** it does so.